# Bias reduction for negative binomial regression models

Tags: r, predict

I am trying to build a model for predicting  Olympics Medal counts.

My data looks like this;

```
year     country    gdp   pop athletes gold tot tot_gold avmedals muslim host comm soviet oneparty
1 2000 Afghanistan   5316 20094        0    0   0      298      915      1    0    0      0        0
2 2000     Algeria  54790 31184       47    1   5      298      915      1    0    0      0        0
3 2000   Argentina 284204 37057      143    0   4      298      915      0    0    0      0        0
4 2000     Armenia   1912  3070       25    0   1      298      915      0    0    1      1        0
5 2000   Australia 415034 19153      617   16  58      298      915      0    1    0      0        0
6 2000     Austria 196800  8012       92    2   3      298      915      0    0    0      0        0
  altitude
1   1790.0
2      1.0
3     10.5
4    989.0
5    605.0
6    170.0
```

I did a bias reduction for negative binomial regression model as a suggestion.

```
mod <- brnb(tot~., data=train_set)
```

although when I try to predict with my test_set I am getting an error is there another way I can predict it and find the rmse?

```
> # Test data
> test_predictions <- predict(mod, newdata = test_set, type = "response")
Error in predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = if (type ==  : 
  (converted from warning) calling predict.lm(<fake-lm-object>) ...
```